# InvalidBSON Exception while reading documents from mongodb

Tags: mongodb, python-3.x, pymongo-3.x

I am getting InvalidBSON exception at third line while reading documents from mongodb using pymongo. I want to continue iteration even after exception anyone know how to do it?

```
   curs=coll.find()
   documents=[]
   for doc in curs:
     documents.append(doc)
```

Comment: I have the same situation, I get an InvalidBSON error when iterating over the results of find. Did you ever figure out the problem? How can the data inside the database be invalid? I thought mongo would make sure all data is valid BSON before saving it.

Comment: looks like my problem was that python was running out of memory

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about this Exception, but you can try this:

```
documents=list(coll.find())
```

Also you can try to use [find_one](http://api.mongodb.com/python/current/api/pymongo/collection.html#pymongo.collection.Collection.find_one) to excluse the problem with memory and reinstall bson package.

Also you can use [try and except](https://www.pythonforbeginners.com/error-handling/python-try-and-except).